# C++ std::random How to implement other distributions?

Tags: c++, std

C++ std statistical distributions has 20 different distributions. However, I am unable to find some other distributions e.g., Burr, Wakeby, Pearson and so on. Could you please suggest me how to implement those distribution easily?

Regards
Sai

Comment: boost (www.boost.org) may have the ones you need.

Comment: Thanks, boost has few additional distributions, however misses many of them I am looking for. Was wandering if there are any generic way where we can define the pdf, cdf and additional parameters and create a new distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most things in the standard library the random functionality defines `Concepts` that can be implemented by a user to extend the library. The ones for Random Number generation are described in 26.5.1 of [N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf). Random Number Distributions are described in 26.5.1.6.

To implement a new distribution you need to implement a Functor that fulfills those requirements and then it can be used with the existing library implementations.